# Can't run Visual Studio Package Manager Console commands in command prompt

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure-devops, nuget

Is it possible to run Visual Studio Package Manager Console commands without installing Visual Studio in Azure Devops or in my local pc ? Basically I need to run `Update-Package` command which is available in visual studio Package Manager Console in order to update particular package and it's dependencies with as well as bindingRedirect versions of in web.config. But when I run `Update-Package` command in powershell, it does not update bindingRedirects. Also nuget CLI commands does not update bindingRedirect versions of dependent packages in web.config either, it just update particular package

Below is the command reference page that I need to run without Visual Studio Package Manager Console;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-update-package

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/nov/29/updating-assembly-redirects-with-nuget Basically run the update and then run Get-Projects | AddBindingRedirect

Comment: @MikeCheel It says that you can use the following command from the Package Manager console. But I need a command that I can run outside of Visual Studio Package Manager Console

Comment: what about nuget.exe?

Comment: @MikeCheel  As I wrote in post , nuget CLI commands does not update bindingRedirect versions of dependent packages in web.config. It just updates the package versions

Comment: It's impossible to run Visual Studio Package Manager Console commands outside Visual Studio. We can see that "[The commands listed here are specific to the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/powershell-reference)"